How to use the same cert used in main page with a iframe for spring boot(2.3)
I had a main page with a iframe whose src is another web site. Both of them are on spring boot servers and enable spring boot security mechanism. After login main page the page within the iframe still request login process. Is that possible to pass the cert used in main page to the iframe page let it auto logon without showing the login page again?
